# Python print error: %d format: a number is required, not tuple

Tags: python, numpy, ipython, typeerror

I get an unexpected error when I try to print:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([11, 21, 31, 41, 51])
it = np.nditer(a, flags=['multi_index'], op_flags=['readwrite'])

while not it.finished:
    i = it.multi_index
    print("%d %d" % (i, a[i]))
    it.iternext()
```

This code generates the error:

```
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not tuple
```

But when I simply do this:

```
for i in xrange(5):
    print("%d %d" % (i, a[i]))
```

Then I get the expected result:

```
0 11
1 21
2 31
3 41
4 51
```

So why do I get this error in the earlier case?

Comment: Try `print(repr((i, a[i])))`

Comment: No need for `nditer` here - [`ndindex`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndindex.html) will do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`i` is not a number.

```
In [69]: it.multi_index
Out[69]: (0,)
```

Use `i[0]` instead.

Answer (score 4):

You should try to use new style formatting

```
print("{} {}".format(i, a[i]))
```

If you really want the index and the element, you can use `enumerate`

```
for i, x in enumerate(np.nditer(a)):
    print("{} {}".format(i, x))
```

And, `multi_index`, as the name implies, is not an integer.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html

Comment: Thank you @cricket_007, very helpful!

Comment: Using `enumerate` with `nditer` is pointless - you already have the value at `it[0]` anyway. If you actually want a 1d index always, use `for ... in np.ndenumerate(a.flat)` and drop `nditer` entirely

Comment: Well, sure. I'm not very familiar with the numpy api

Answer (score 1):

You're using it.multi_index that returns a tuple of indices.

As your array is 1D, replace `i=it.multi_index` with the index you wish to extract.

In your case, it should be
`i=it.multi_index[0]`

Answer (score 1):

`i` is of type `tuple`, use `it.multi_index[0]` to get the first element like below:

```
while not it.finished:
    i = it.multi_index[0]
    print("%d %d" % (i, a[i]))  # The better is using "{} {}".format(i, a[i])
    it.iternext()
```